# Cannot pass options as parameter in MongoClient following Jest docs

Tags: mongodb, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests for one of my classes using Jest as framework. I'm following this documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/mongodb.
It says that I need to connect to the database using:

```
connection = await MongoClient.connect(globalThis.__MONGO_URI__, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
```

but when I try to do this in my code it doesn't recognize the "userNewUrlParser" nor the "useUnifiedTopology" fields in the options object. The exact message is:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useNewUrlParser' does not exist in type 'Callback<MongoClient>'.
```

How can I fix this unwanted behavious?

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb/issues/419#issue-1620350063